# Query related to Dynamic forms

Tags: lightning-app-builder, dynamic-forms

I need to implement dynamic forms in a lightning record page. when i upgraded the record detail to dynamic forms, the visual force page inside the layout are not migrated.

how to add the vf page between the fields in dynamic forms?

Comment: Are you trying to add vf page component inside field section?

Comment: Yes.Is that possible?@SaiPraveenKakkirala

Comment: No you cannot add it inside field section as it is separate component. You may have to add it outside the field section.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We cannot add Vf page component into field section in Dynamic form as those two were different components. You can only add fields inside field section.

You need to add the vf page separately under field section if you need it.